# require js + backbone + marionette: Cannot read property 'Marionette' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I just started off learning backbone and want to manage my dependencies using require js.

My code is as follows:

main.js:

```
//Require.js 
require.config({

paths   : {
    jQuery          : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min', 
    jQueryUI        : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min', 
    lodash          : 'libs/lodash/lodash', 
    backbone        : 'libs/backbone/backbone',
    marionette      : 'libs/marionette/marionette' 
}, 

shim    : {
    backbone: {
        deps        : ['jQuery', 'lodash'], 
        exports     : 'backbone'
    }, 
    marionette: {
        deps        : ['backbone'], 
        exports     : 'marionette'
    }
}

}); 

require(['initialize'], function(initializer){
    alert("initialized");
});
```

initialize.js:

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette'], function(Backbone, Marionette){

        var appZwoop = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

        var options = {

        };

        //Initialize functions 
        appZwoop.addInitializer(function(options){

        }); 

        //Application events 
        appZwoop.on("initialize:before", function(options){

        });

        appZwoop.on("initialize:after", function(options){

        });

        //Start the application 
        appZwoop.start(options);

        appZwoop.addRegions({
            mainRegion : "#mainRegion", 
            headerRegion: "#headerRegion"
        });

        return appZwoop; 

}
```

The browser console throws me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Marionette' of undefined

What am I doing wrong ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you Backbone shim to capitalize `Backbone` in the exports:

```
backbone: {
    deps        : ['jQuery', 'lodash'], 
    exports     : 'Backbone'
},
```

because Backbone defines itself as `Backbone` and not `backbone`. There may be a problem elsewhere but you definitely have to do this.

Comment: Very nice that was it, thanks man! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when SO allows me.

Comment: as of now you just have to it as Marionette since they upgrade it to AMD friendly